# How to show Google Website is Beta Version

Tags: google, google-search-console, web-development

I am developing a new version of my old website. The new version is slightly to be released in the coming month. I would like to show Google , **that my new version of my website is in beta mode** for few days/months. Is there any possible way.

Since the website in beta mode , there might be some flaws or 404's may occurs. Because of these i don't like to drop my traffic in  Google search. So if i say beta version to google is there any consideration in traffic drops.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such thing. You can however use robots.txt to limit what pages google can or cannot index during your "beta". This way, don't index the pages which can 404 if it is that important.